# Summation where upper bound is a function?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

I was attempting to understand asymptotic expansions when I came across this simple expression:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{x^2}n.
$$

Of course, being an amateur mathematician, I threw it into [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20from%201%20to%20%28x%5E2%29%20n) to see what it would say. To my surprise, it spit out an equation: $\sum_{n=1}^{x^2} n = \frac{1}{2} x^2 (x^2 + 1)$! My question is how? I attempted to approximate this sum by an integral, but I didn't quite get the right results:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{x^2}n \approx \int_1^{x^{2}} ndn \\ \int_1^{x^{2}} ndn = \frac{n^2} {2}|_{1}^{x^2} = \frac{1}{2}(x^4-1)
$$

Is it applying the Euler–Maclaurin formula? Or is there some other formula or simple manipulation I just don't see?

Furthermore, as an aside, what can we say about functions of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{f(x)}g(n)?
$$

Do they have simple expansions? What can we say about them?

Comment: I was very confused as to why a factorial appeared in your summation. Then it hit me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number#Formula) that $$\sum_{n=1}^{u} n = \frac{u(u+1)}{2}$$

Plugging in $u = x^2$, we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{x^2} n = \frac{x^2(x^2+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

WAs proposed  result is  not  that   plausible, since we might rather assume in such cases $x$ being a real number.

> According to rules when using the sigma-symbol $\sum$ we have for real  $x\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{x^2} n}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor x^2\rfloor} n\\
> &=1+2+\cdots+\lfloor x^2\rfloor\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2}\left\lfloor x^2\right\rfloor\left(\left\lfloor x^2\right\rfloor+1\right)}
> \end{align*}
>   where *[$\lfloor  a\rfloor$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)* is the greatest integer less or equal to $a$. See for instance   chapter 2: *Sums* , section 2.1 *Notation* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)*
>   by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik.

In the more general case we have, assuming $f(x)\geq 1$:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{f(x)}g(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{\left\lfloor f(x)\right\rfloor}g(n)=g(1)+g(2)+\cdots+g\left(\left\lfloor f(x)\right\rfloor\right)
\end{align*}

**Note:** We additionally have the rule $\sum_{n=a}^{b}f(n)=0$ if $b<a$ (see the referenced book).

Answer (score 0):

The summation function works as the upper limit is an integer. In fact the sum is: $S_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. So if $n=f(x)$ then: $S_{f_{(x)}}=\frac{f_{(x)}(f_{(x)}-1)}{2}$.